# Hide SharePoint sppkg from site contents

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

How do we hide all the solutions deployed in a site from site contents? I am structuring my solution to have separate project for each web part. So far I have 7 web parts each deployed with a dedicated sppkg file. I don't want to deploy these projects to the whole tenant, but at the same time I don't want to show all of these web parts in site contents since I will have even more web parts to be deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can’t do that. There is no supported way of hiding apps installed in a site from the site contents view.